# Aligning equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

How can I align the two right handed equation as done for the two left handed ones in the screenshot blew:
[image]

Here is my code regarding this part:

```
\begin{align*}
u &= e^{-3x} 
&&\text{ d}v = \cosh(5x)\text{ d}x \\
\text{d}u &= -3e^{-3x} \text{ d}x  
&& v = \frac{1}{5}\sinh(5x).
\end{align*}.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have not added the alignment marker `&`  before `=` in the right hand equations

Answer (score 2):

Two alignment points require `3` & (the 2nd `&` indicates a new column, the 3rd is for the alignment point in that column). Also it would be shorter to write a macro for the differential symbol, with a correct spacing. Here's one, borrowed  from an answer on this site, to add to your preamble. Note that, with `alignat` you have control on the horizontal separation between the two columns:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{\kern0pt\mathrm{d}}\!{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
u &= e^{-3x} & \dd v &= \cosh(5x)\dd x \\
\dd u &= -3e^{-3x} \dd x & v &= \frac{1}{5}\sinh(5x).
\end{align*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
u &= e^{-3x} &\dd v & = \cosh(5x)\dd x \\
\dd u &= -3e^{-3x} \dd x & \hspace{3em} v &= \frac{1}{5}\sinh(5x).
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you say 3 but you have 4 `&` in each row in your code section

Comment: @David Carlisle: As I didn't test, I didn't  see there were only two TeX lines. I'll fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @Campa: Even with the corrected code?

Comment: Why not change all d's?

Comment: @egreg: Just because I forgot to check… I messed up with my clipboard manager. I'll fix the code. Thanks for pointing it!